# Panel data with two time factors

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data

I've got some data that come from a economic experiment. I'm trying to fit a model using plm() function (plm package). I'm following a very good tutorial (Panel data econometrics in R: The plm package). The only problem is the function allow the following data structure:

```
individuals / time / x1...xp / y
```

and I've got the following structure:

```
individuals / time 1 (session) / time 2 (round) / ....
```

I was reading the function gls() (nlme package), so may be I can explore the autocorrelation structure, add it to the model and treat session and rounds as dummy variables. But what about individuals? They are the same within each session, but change between sessions. So individuals is a random factor, isn't it?.

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: what model do you want to fit and what is your identification strategy?  fixed effects i.e. difference in differences?  how are you estimating the variance covariance matrix?  cluster-sandwich?  answers to these questions would be me (and perhaps others) to give you advice.  generally its good to say what you want to do and why you want to do it before settling on a particular package.  but then again I program almost everything from scratch.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the number of rounds and sessions in your experiment?

Comment: Hi everyone, I added more details in the following question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50374/how-to-deal-with-two-time-factors-in-panel-data-modelling-using-plm-package-in-r