# How to deal with two time variables in panel data modelling using PLM package in R?

Tags: r, experiment-design, econometrics, panel-data

We have question regarding the analysis of panel data in R ([plm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf)) which was observed over two time scales.

As way of a background, we have completed an economic experiment with a group of 6-8 students, which is completed over 18 sessions (time 1) with 12 rounds per session (time 2). We have three treatments and each treatment is replicated three times (3 session * 12 rounds = 36 times). In each session there are six players making decisions each round (as some are removed prior due to a bidding process). We have set out our experimental design below in Table 1 for greater clarity.  We have also included a table showing what the dataset looks like (Table 2). The treatments test three different scenarios (3 levels) across three different types of fisheries (3 levels).

So our question is how should we deal with my two time variables (session and round) given that some participants play in more than one round and session? We understand that we cannot ignore rounds, as a player's decision will be influenced by what happens in previous rounds, in the current and previous sessions. The plm function doesn’t allow you to analyze two time variables; therefore, should we set one time variable as a factor(e.i. `as.factor(sessions)`)?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is of interest to me too.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: yes, please have a look at the following papers https://doi.org/10.1093/icesjms/fsv148  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ocecoaman.2015.01.008